# time based movement sliding object

Tags: c++

At the moment i have a function that moves my object based on FPS, if the frames have not passed it wont do anything.

It works fine if the computer can run it at that speed.

How would i use time based and move it based on the time?

Here is my code:

```
typedef unsigned __int64 u64;

auto toolbarGL::Slide() -> void
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li = {};
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li);
    u64 freq = static_cast<u64>(li.QuadPart); // clock ticks per second
    u64 period = 60;  // fps
    u64 delay = freq / period;    // clock ticks between frame paints

    u64 start = 0, now = 0;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    start = static_cast<u64>(li.QuadPart);

    while (true)
    {
        // Waits to be ready to slide
        // Keeps looping till stopped then starts to wait again
        SlideEvent.wait();

        QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
        now = static_cast<u64>(li.QuadPart);
        if (now - start >= delay)
        {
            if (slideDir == SlideFlag::Right)
            {
                if (this->x < 0)
                {
                    this->x += 5;
                    this->controller->Paint();
                }
                else
                    SlideEvent.stop();
            }
            else if (slideDir == SlideFlag::Left)
            {
                if (this->x > -90)
                {
                    this->x -= 5;
                    this->controller->Paint();
                }
                else
                    SlideEvent.stop();
            }
            else
                SlideEvent.stop();

            start = now;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your objects by time difference. We need to have start timestamp and then count difference on each iteration of global loop. So global loop is very important too, it has to work all the time. My example shows just call update method for your objects. All your objects should depend on time not FPS. Fps shows different behavior on different computers and even same computer can show different fps because of others processes running in background.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <unistd.h>

//Function to update all objects
void Update( float dt )
{
    //For example
    //for( auto Object : VectorObjects )
    //{
    //    Object->Update(dt);
    //}
}

int main()
{
    typedef std::chrono::duration<float> FloatSeconds;
    auto OldMs = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch();

    const uint32_t SleepMicroseconds = 100;

    //Global loop
    while (true)
    {
        auto CurMs = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch();
        auto DeltaMs = CurMs - OldMs;
        OldMs = CurMs;

        //Cast delta time to float seconds
        auto DeltaFloat = std::chrono::duration_cast<FloatSeconds>(DeltaMs);

        std::cout << "Seconds passed since last update: " << DeltaFloat.count() << " seconds" << std::endl;

        //Update all object by time as float value.
        Update( DeltaFloat.count() );

        // Sleep to give time for system interaction
        usleep(SleepMicroseconds);

        // Any other actions to calculate can be here
        //...
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For this example in console you can see something like this:

```
Seconds passed since last update: 0.002685 seconds
Seconds passed since last update: 0.002711 seconds
Seconds passed since last update: 0.002619 seconds
Seconds passed since last update: 0.00253 seconds
Seconds passed since last update: 0.002509 seconds
Seconds passed since last update: 0.002757 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Your time base logic seems to be incorrect, here's a sample code snippet. The speed of the object should be same irrespective of speed of the system. Instead of `QueryPerformanceFrequency` which is platform dependent, use std::chrono.

```
void animate(bool& stop)
{
    static float speed = 1080/5; // = 1080px/ 5sec = 5sec to cross screen
    static std::chrono::system_clock::time_point start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    float fps;
    int object_x = 1080;

    while(!stop)
    {
        //calculate factional time 
        auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        auto diff = now - start;
        auto lapse_milli = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(diff);
        auto lapse_sec = lapse_milli.count()/1000;

        //apply to object
        int incr_x = speed * lapse_sec ;
        object_x -= incr_x;
        if( object_x <0) object_x = 1080;

        // render object here        

        fps = lapse_milli.count()/1000;
        //print fps

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100)); // change to achieve a desired fps rate
        start = now;
    }

}
```